# DialogFragment use DarkTheme

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

When I execute that code I only get the whitetheme, how can I get that blacktheme with the exclamation mark? I don't see any information on how to use it on the android developer page.

[image: DialogBox]

Code:

```
public class NetworkDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setMessage("Bitte überprüfen Sie Ihre Wi-Fi- oder MobileFunk-Verbinung und versuchen Sie es erneut.")
            .setTitle("Keine Internetverbindung")
            .setNegativeButton("Abbrechen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            }).setPositiveButton("Einstellungen", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS));
                }
            });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

Comment: The dialog style is based on your app theme

Comment: But shouldn't I have at least the exclamation mark?

Comment: no thats just an icon you provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the exclamation mark i added this pice of code: `.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)` and to change the color i changed me default theme to Holo Dark.